# Function returning garbage values but not all of them in C

Tags: c, memory-management

**So here's what I need to accomplish:**

- Enter a sequence of whole numbers that end with 0
- Out of those numbers - calculate its square root and check if it's an odd or even number.
- Make use of while or do-while loops in the process.

I have my no. of elements set to 4 for now, but no matter what number I set, **roughly half of them come out as garbage values** in the end.

I assume this is a pointer related issue or a memory leak somewhere, I'm just not sure. Any input would be appreciated

```
    int num_of_elements = 4;

//function declarations
int* check_num(int i, int number[num_of_elements]);

//main function
int main() {


    //local variables
    int num[5];
    int i;

    printf("\nEnter a number that ends with 0");

    for (i=0;i<num_of_elements;i++) {
        do {
            printf("\n%d.Enter a number: ", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        } while (num[i] % 10 != 0);

        printf("\nElement %d: %d\n", i+1, num[i]);
    }

    int j = 0;

    while (j<num_of_elements) {
        check_num(j, &num[j]);
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}

//function that takes the square root and checks if it's an odd or even number

int* check_num(int j, int number[num_of_elements]) {

    int val;

    printf("\nnumber[%d] is %d",j,number[j]);

    val = sqrt(number[j]);
    printf("\nsquare root is is %d", val);

        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n%d is a an even number squared", number[j]);
        } else {
            printf("\n%d is an odd number squared", number[j]);
        }
    printf("\n");

    return number;
}
```

Comment: Where are your `#include`s?

Comment: `check_num(j, &num[j]);` ==> `check_num(j, num);`

Comment: @pmg: A bit terse?

Comment: LOL @500 I love terse on mobile phone

Comment: What is the purpose of the return value of `check_num()`? The calculation `val = sqrt(number[j]);` may not always do what you expect. It first converts the `int` value to `double`, which may change the value, calculate the square root as a `double` value and truncate it to an integer. If you pass `10` you will probably get the result `3`. You should at least cross check that `val * val` is equal to the original number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can see, there is only one error:

The call to `check_num` must be changed from `check_num(j, &num[j]);` to `check_num(j, &num);` otherwise you are passing for example the address `num[j]` and from that address you are trying to access the `j` element, so you are trying to access the `j+j` element.

Comment: well, also check_num(j, num); will work, rather i think it's better, because check_num with & can modify the pointer, is a array pointer can be changed in C..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that int array into an int array variable. Instead of that , you can directly give it to the int variable.
see this code.

```
int num_of_elements=4;

//function declarations
void check_num(int i, int number);

//main function
int main() {


    //local variables
    int num[5];
    int i;

    printf("\nEnter a number that ends with 0");

    for (i=0;i<num_of_elements;i++) {
        do {
            printf("\n%d.Enter a number: ", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        } while (num[i] % 10 != 0);

        printf("\nElement %d: %d\n", i+1, num[i]);
    }

    int j = 0;

    while (j<num_of_elements) {

        check_num(j,num[j]);
        printf("%d\n",num[j]);
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}




void check_num(int j, int number) {




    int val;

    printf("\nnumber[%d] is %d",j,number);

    val = sqrt((number));
    printf("\nsquare root is  %d", val);

        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n%d is a an even number squared", number);
        } else {
            printf("\n%d is an odd number squared", number);
        }
    printf("\n");

    //return number;
}
```